# setting smtp on php.ini with authentication

Tags: iis-7, smtp, php, dyndns

I'm setting up smtp on `IIS` web server using `php`

In the `php.ini` file the smtp section as follow:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = outbound.mailhop.org
smtp_port = 25

auth_username = my_dyndns_username
auth_password = pwd

sendmail_from = no-reply@website.com
```

The problem is that when I try to call the mail() function the smtp server says

```
SMTP server response: 550 You must authenticate to use Dyn Standard SMTP
```

where can I tell IIS (or php) the username and password in order to be authenticated on dyndns server?

Dario

Comment: it looks like you'll need to either use a mail library or write your own to talk directly to the mail server

Answer (score 1):

I found [swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to be a solution form my problem.

with this simple script I have everything works

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('outbound.mailhop.org', 25)
                ->setUsername('user')
                ->setPassword('pwd');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);


$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject($sbj)
        ->setFrom($from)
        ->setReplyTo($replyTo)
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setBody($msg);

$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

[here](http://swiftmailer.org/pdf/Swiftmailer.pdf) is the book on how to do with other functions/parameters

Answer (score 0):

To use `SMTP` Authentication with PHP you'll want to use the Mail `PEAR` extension ... here is a [nice post](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm) telling you how to use it.

Basically, you'll need to install the [extension](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) ([windows instructions](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-pear-on-windows.html)) and then configure a bit of code something like this (from the post above):

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
 $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "mail.example.com";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: but how to do that without external libraries?

I mean, I want to use pure php.ini configuration... is that possible?

Comment: Good luck getting that to work without the `PEAR` lib ... I've never seen it done. BTW, `PEAR` isn't really an external lib, it's extensions (i.e. PHP functions) and it's hosted by the people that make PHP http://pear.php.net/ --- it's not unlike writing your own function to do it, except their functions are likely to be better :)